# Keep a perl script running

Tags: perl, mqtt, anyevent

I have a perl script that subscribes to a message queue using AnyEvent::MQTT.

At the minute all I want it to do is print out when it get's a message. I'm totally new to perl so I'm using the demo code it comes with which includes a bit that publishes anything on the STDIN as a message - this works great, and I can see all the messages received.

This code looks as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use AnyEvent::MQTT;
my $mqtt = AnyEvent::MQTT->new;
my $cv = $mqtt->subscribe(topic => '/AlarmMode',
                           callback => sub {
                               my ($topic, $message) = @_;
                                       print $topic, ' ', $message, "\n"
                                   });

my $qos = $cv->recv; # subscribed, negotiated QoS == $qos



  # publish line-by-line from file handle
      $cv =  $mqtt->publish(handle => \*STDIN,
                            topic => '/topic');
```

The issue I have is that if I remove everything after the comment `publish line-by-line from file handle` then my app exits as soon as it's ran.

I've tried including a while loop that sleeps for 5 seconds but that does't work (the app just looks like it's hung).

I know I need to do *something* to tell the app just to stay alive and chill, but I don't know what that command is :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you block with something that isn't AE-aware (e.g. `sleep`), then AE events won't be handled.

To sleep while allowing the AE events to be handled, one normally uses

```
my $done_cv = AE::cv;
$done_cv->recv;
```

Use `$done_cv->send;` to end the sleep. For example, If you wanted to sleep for 5 seconds, you'd use

```
my $sleep_cv = AE::cv;
my $w = AE::timer(5, 0, $sleep_cv);  # Short for AE::timer(5, 0, sub { $sleep_cv->send });
$sleep_cv->recv;
```

Comment: My last line would be `my $qos = $cv->recv; # subscribed, negotiated QoS == $qos`. Would that not wait then?

Comment: It does wait. It waits for the subscription to be complete, because that's when `send` is called on that cv. But you want to keep waiting beyond that. [Renamed the vars in my answer to avoid confusion.]